# angular2 - get json file content into my class attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, typescript, angular

newbie here (first angular2 day)

I have a class with 3 fields: `id` and `name` which are passed to the constructor, and a third field called `data` which should receive the content of a JSON file

```
export class Hero {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    data: Object;

    constructor(id: string, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

        //retrieve JSON and assign it to this.data
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onload = function(){
            var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            this.data = result;
        };

        //get the json file according to the object id
        request.open("get", id+".json", true);
        request.send();

    }
}
```

then i instantiate the object like this

```
new Hero("hero1", "Hero 1");
```

The problem is that instruction `this.data = result;` won't work because `this` refers to the request object, not the class.

Plus, i don't know if this is the correct way to proceed (and to get the json file). I'm still quite  lost in angular2. Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `http.get()` (wouldn't solve your actual problem)?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i saw some examples with `http.get()` where the `http` object is a constructor parameter, and actually i don't get it. If i add it then the instance `new Hero("hero1", "Hero 1");` won't be valid anymore (missing 1 parameter)

Comment: `Http` is provided when you add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` (in `bootstrap()` or `providers: [...]` of `AppComponent`. When the component is created by Angular, it passes an `Http` instance (service) and you can use it to make requests. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks, i'll try out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function instead

```
    request.onload = () => {
        var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        this.data = result;
    };
```

Comment: this give me error `Property 'responseText' does not exist on type 'Hero'.`

Comment: Where should it come from. I don't see `responseText` declared or assigned to in your code. I guess you mean `request.responseText`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like:

```
export class Hero {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    data: Object;

    constructor(id: string, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onload = this.onDataRecieved.bind(this, request);

        request.open("get", id + ".json", true);
        request.send();
    }

    private onDataRecieved(request: XMLHttpRequest): void {
        let result = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        this.data = JSON.parse(result);
    }
}
```